# how to add laravel conditional validation

Tags: laravel, validation, laravel-9, laravel-validation, laravel-request

I want to add conditional validation to my request. I have different user roles and different fields for some users.

I want to check if the user role is business then some fields are required and if the user is a worker then business user fields are not required.

```
 $this->validate($this->_request, [
      'name' => 'required',
      'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
      'phone' => ['required', 'max:22'],
      'municipality_of_origin' => 'required',
  ]);
```

These are required for all users. Now I want to check if a user is business

```
 if($role == 'business'){
      'company_name' => 'required',
      'company_title' => 'required',
 }

 if($role == 'worker'){
      'designation' => 'required',
      'salary' => 'required',
 }

 $data = $request->safe()->only('name', 'email', 'phone', 'municipality_of_origin');
 $user = User::create($data);

 if($role == 'business){
    $business_user = $request->safe()->only('company_name', 'company_title');
    $business_user['user_id'] = $user->id;

    // business is hasOne relationship with User model.
    $user->business->create($business_user);
 }
```

Is there any best way to handle this type of conditional validation in laravel? I'm using Laravel 9.

I try Form validation but don't understand how to use FormRequest for this type of validation.

```
$rules = [];

$rules['name'] = 'required';
$rules['email'] = ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:users'];
$rules['phone'] = ['required', 'max:22'];
$rules['municipality_of_origin'] = 'required';

if ($this->attributes->has('some-key')) {
     $rules['other-key'] = 'required|unique|etc';
}
```

and problem is $this->attributes->has() method return null all the time.

Comment: don't you have access to a `$request` object in that FormRequest?

Comment: try with `request()->attributes->has()`

Comment: You left out how you get the role, can you include this?